# PHP Spliting then Combining

Tags: php, split

for example I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'eat|drink today|tomorrow';
```

from above string I want to get the result

```
eat today, eat tomorrow, drink today, drink tomorrow,
```

what I have to do? I try with split but not so good the result. thanks.

Comment: If you have tried something, please add the code to the question to show your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) a several times:

```
$string = 'eat|drink today|tomorrow';

$tmp = explode(' ',$string);        // eat|drink today|tomorrow  => [eat|drink, today|tomorrow]
$tmp1 = explode('|',$tmp[0]);       // eat|drink                => [eat, drink]
$tmp2 = explode('|',$tmp[1]);       // today|tomorrow           => [today, tomorrow]

foreach($tmp1 as $eat){
    foreach($tmp2 as $today){
        echo "$eat $today, ";
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/dSjRD)**

Output:

```
eat today, eat tomorrow, drink today, drink tomorrow,
```

Comment: Why do you use `$ind` in the foreach when it's not used? And why use the same variable twice, that just overwrites the first one and makes the code confusing for someone who does not understand it.

Comment: @Andreas, where is it?)

Comment: @Andreas, yeap, almost immediately. And I was wondered why you didn't saw possibility to refresh the answer and left such comment.

Comment: There are more devices than computer you can use to browse SO.

Comment: @Andreas, doesn't matter. Your comment doesn't has a sense.

Comment: Oh dear.... Let me speak clearly then. If you use a device that does not show updates on questions and answers until you have reloaded the page then you will not see said changes (obviously). I use a phone and do not see changes untill I have reloaded the page. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Andreas, it was clear after words `more devices`, come down) I'm just telling you about the sense of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

One way is with leveraging explode & implode and as we are explicit here (you know values and size) this would work.
Might be a quicker nicer way with a regular expression to get the first string instantly split, but this was a solution that came in mind at first glance.

```php
$string = 'eat|drink today|tomorrow';

// First split the string by the space between them, then by the pipe in separate arrays.
$removedSpace = explode(' ', $string);

// The action items.
$actions = explode('|', $removedSpace[0]);
// The periods/time of day items.
$dayPeriods = explode('|', $removedSpace[1]);

$final = [];

// Loop through actions and for each day period, generate the string.
foreach ($actions as $action) {
    foreach ($dayPeriods as $dayPeriod) {
        $final[] = $action . ' ' . $dayPeriod;
    }
}

$finalString = implode(', ', $final); // Your desired result in string format without last comma.
```

[EDIT]
I was writing up my reply while the first reply was published.
Feel free to delete this.
[/EDIT]

Comment: This is a better solution since, as you say, you don't have the trailing comma.